# Unexpected non-root current context found when extracting remote context

Tags: kotlin, apache-kafka, grpc, ktor, open-telemetry

Our backend is built with Kotlin & Ktor pair, plus we use the OpenTelemetry Java agent. The inter-process communication is done thru Kafka & gRPC protocols. So, if I enable debug logs for the otel agent with `-Dotel.javaagent.debug=true` option, deploy any of ours services and wait until some of requests finish wandering in our backend, then I'll see lots of `Unexpected non-root current context found when extracting remote context` errors. Some of them are also followed by `It contains this span: {...}` kind of messages.

I tried to debug the agent and found the place where the error message is being logged. The code there looks like this:

```
public static void debugContextLeakIfEnabled() {
...
    Context current = Context.current();
    if (current != Context.root()) {
      logger.severe("Unexpected non-root current context found when extracting remote context!");
      Span currentSpan = Span.fromContextOrNull(current);
      if (currentSpan != null) {
        logger.log(SEVERE, "It contains this span: {0}", currentSpan);
      }
...
```

and what I debugged there is that the result of calling `Context.root()` is always empty for me. If I make a gRPC call I have something like this `{grpc-context=io.grpc.Context@6bbf0558}` in the `current` context, if it's a Kafka call then something like this:

```
{
    opentelemetry-trace-span-key=SdkSpan{
        traceId=7fdfd243a0b269e350356749445da3a8, 
        spanId=b2c00099937f0e04, 
        parentSpanContext=ImmutableSpanContext{
            traceId=00000000000000000000000000000000, 
            spanId=0000000000000000, 
            traceFlags=00, 
            traceState=ArrayBasedTraceState{
                entries=[]
            }, 
            remote=false, 
            valid=false
        }, 
        name=CustomCoroutineDispatcher.launch, 
        kind=INTERNAL, 
        attributes=AttributesMap{
            data={
                code.function=launch, 
                thread.id=1, 
                code.namespace=<our packages>.CustomCoroutineDispatcher, 
                thread.name=main
            }, 
            capacity=128, 
            totalAddedValues=4
        }, 
        status=ImmutableStatusData{
            statusCode=UNSET, 
            description=
        }, 
        totalRecordedEvents=0, 
        totalRecordedLinks=0, 
        startEpochNanos=1678199892119957000, 
        endEpochNanos=1678199892165366305
    }, 
    opentelemetry-traces-local-root-span=SdkSpan{
        traceId=7fdfd243a0b269e350356749445da3a8, 
        spanId=b2c00099937f0e04, 
        parentSpanContext=ImmutableSpanContext{
            traceId=00000000000000000000000000000000, 
            spanId=0000000000000000, 
            traceFlags=00, 
            traceState=ArrayBasedTraceState{
                entries=[]
            }, 
            remote=false, 
            valid=false
        }, 
        name=CustomCoroutineDispatcher.launch, 
        kind=INTERNAL, 
        attributes=AttributesMap{
            data={
                code.function=launch, 
                thread.id=1, 
                code.namespace=<our packages>.CustomCoroutineDispatcher, 
                thread.name=main
            }, 
            capacity=128, 
            totalAddedValues=4
        }, 
        status=ImmutableStatusData{
            statusCode=UNSET, 
            description=
        }, 
        totalRecordedEvents=0, 
        totalRecordedLinks=0, 
        startEpochNanos=1678199892119957000, 
        endEpochNanos=1678199892165366305
    }
}
```

For the last, I also tried to debug the `ImmutableSpanContext` class, because I found a doc there that says:

> If the traceId or the spanId are invalid (ie. do not conform to the requirements for hexadecimal ids of the appropriate lengths), both will be replaced with the standard "invalid" versions (i.e. all '0's)

and it seems exactly what I got in my second current context. But for some reason I had no success - the debugger didn't stop there (I admit that I could do something wrong, though I can't double-check in the near future).

So, I have 4 questions:

1. Woah, I just found [this page](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/blob/main/docs/supported-libraries.md) and if I remember correctly - I didn't see none of these libraries in our project, neither [this](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/tree/main/instrumentation/grpc-1.6/library), nor [that](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/tree/main/instrumentation/kafka/kafka-clients/kafka-clients-2.6/library).  Could it be the case?
2. As I understood while reading the documentation, the context transfers from one service to another via the *Context Propagation* mechanism. I also found the [OTEL_PROPAGATORS](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-specification/blob/main/specification/sdk-environment-variables.md#general-sdk-configuration) env, which we don't use for our services. Should we add it?
3. How serious is this error and what can it lead to? I checked our Grafana and the traces looked pretty OK there, filled with data and hierarchically arranged. What's this error about then?
4. And the last (and banal), how to solve the problem, or at least where I need to look more carefully to understand what is wrong?

Some of libraries versions:

```
io.grpc=1.42.0
io.grpc.grpc-kotlin-stub=1.2.0
io.ktor=1.6.4
io.opentelemetry=1.17.0
org.apache.kafka=2.8.0
org.jetbrains.kotlinx.coroutines=1.6.4
```

OTEL envs:

```
OTEL_EXPERIMENTAL_EXPORTER_OTLP_RETRY_ENABLED=true
OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_TRACES_PROTOCOL=grpc
OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_TRACES_COMPRESSION=gzip
OTEL_METRICS_EXPORTER=none
OTEL_RESOURCE_ATTRIBUTES=host.name=dev,service.namespace=test,service.version=0.0.1,container.name=test,container.image.tag=14a50b79
OTEL_TRACES_EXPORTER=otlp
OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT=http://otel-col:4317
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-javaagent:/tmp/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar -Dotel.instrumentation.jdbc.enabled=false -Dotel.javaagent.debug=true -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005
OTEL_EXPERIMENTAL_SDK_ENABLED=true
OTEL_SERVICE_NAME=test
```

Comment: Any luck with this issue? I faced with same.

Comment: @Fesswood Hi! otel developers "fixed" this by moving the message to the `WARN` level in `1.27.0` version of the agent. Here is the discussion https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/issues/8536